# how to fade / highlight respective div on link click in jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I have following what I have tried so far `fiddle` http://jsfiddle.net/BLPgX/ I want to fade div instead of adding class and removing class.Also if user copy link like http://www.myweb.com/test/ques.jsp#Faq1
how to `fade` div?

Thanks & regards

Comment: Fade the background you mean?

Comment: yes fade background..

Comment: second link does not work.

Comment: sorry i just given 2nd link for example for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15561550/fade-out-in-div-on-page-load#15561609 see div background fadeIn(orange-color)

Comment: try this link http://jqueryui.com/animate/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i did in following way

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
                if(document.location.href.indexOf('#') > -1){
                    var id = location.hash.replace("#","");
                    $thisAns = $("#"+id);
                    $thisAns.addClass("highlightAns");
                        // Remove that class after 2 seconds                       
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            $thisAns.removeClass("highlightAns");
                        },2000);
                }
                else{
                    console.log("URL does not contains Id");
                }    

                $('.highlight').on('click', function() {
                    // Get the div that should be higlighted now
                    var id = $(this).attr('href').replace("#", "");
                    $thisAns = $('#'+id);
                    // Add highlightAns class
                    $thisAns.addClass("highlightAns");
                    // Remove that class after 2 seconds                       
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        $thisAns.removeClass("highlightAns");
                    },2000);
                });
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like this? It fades in and out.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9HHE3/1/)

Gave all the answers a class of `answers` and in that class I gave the css `transition:2s;` which is how long the class add and remove takes.

Comment: works well but if i copy link address as in my case(http://localhost:8080/test/ques.jsp#Faq5) to another browser tab then it does not fade..

Comment: It wont fade because you need to click the link again, it's triggered on question click. @Sumit

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
     // Add highlightAns class
       $thisAns.addClass("highlightAns").fadeIn("slow");

    // Remove that class after 2 seconds                       
      setTimeout(function(){
           $thisAns.removeClass("highlightAns").fadeOut("slow");
      },2000);
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/BLPgX/1/)